# How to setup Samba to register with an Active Directory Domain Controller?

Tags: networking, samba, dns

I am trying to setup an Ubuntu 14.04 server on a windows network.  The server has a static IP address assigned to it.  I need to be able to register the hostname (argo) of the server with AD domain controller so that users of the windows workstations can type in http://argo in their address bar and arrive at the website hosted on argo.  The server is working and if I type the IP address of the server I can access the website on it from any of the workstations.

The information I have is:

- The webserver's (argo's) IP address
- The netmask
- The default gateway
- The IP address for the Windows AD domain controller (The DNS server address) which is also the WINS address.
- The DNS suffix (is this considered the DNS domain name?)

I think I have /etc/hosts configured properly but I'm unsure of what exactly needs to be put in /etc/network/interfaces (since Ubuntu overwrite resolv.conf).

I'm also unsure of which Samba commands need to be run.  When I tried to run the command net ads dns register -P I got an ads_connect: No logon servers error.

So, given this situation, how do I register argo with the AD domain controller?

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what your asking is achievable, somebody else might be able to point you in a better direction but here is my solution.

You could add a DNS record in your domain controller (Ensure replication is setup if you have multiple Domain Controllers), this would enable your users to browse to http://argo.mydomain.net

The problem lies where if you are using the samba back end DNS server then you will have to use *subdomain.mydomain.net*, I'm not sure if other DNS servers like BIND would enable you to do this but you can also fire up a test machine and give it ago.

There may be other ways that involve joining your web server into the domain (Possible security implications) and that might allow you to address the machine in the desired format.

But I wouldn't know, I use the method described first to resolve our users to internal websites.